# In C1 CMS How to create a list dynamically by getting input from user at the function property window?

Tags: list, razor, drop-down-menu, c1-cms, orckestra-cms

Actually I am trying to create two controls one is drop down and another is List. Both are similar and easy for static values or values which are already stored somewhere.

But what I want is, I want the Power user to create or add / edit list items at the run time ( When he is inserting function to the page )

so similar concept to this : http://jsfiddle.net/DVbGY/1/

```
<div data-role="content">   

    <div id="items">
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="item" />
    <input type="button" value="Add item to list" onclick="appendToList()"/>
```

```
<script>
var listCreated = false;    
function appendToList(){    
if(!listCreated){
    $("#items").append("<ul id='list' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'></ul>");
    listCreated = true;
    $("#items").trigger("create");
}
var value = $("#item").val();
var listItem = "<li>" + value + "</li>";
$("#list").append(listItem);

}
</script>
```

but in the function property window.

Currently I am using comma separated list from user but its not viable solution as my next step is to add url as well with the input data from user so Lets say user wants to create a drop-down button and user is adding items and associating particular link to its items.

[image]

As you can see in above image i am getting data from user but instead of that text box i want to use above mentioned similar concept.

How can I make this possible ? or Is it possible in C1-CMS ? if yes please explain with Example in detail.

Thank you for your time and thanks reading this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with the currently built in widgets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pauli. I was wondering that if its not possible with the currently built in widgets then is it possible to create custom widget and accomplish this ? or any how I can get kind of dynamic grid system or something in that place so that user can enter data at the run time ?

Comment: @PratikShukla its def. possible to create such a widget - basically all it needs to be able to is parse and save back a comma-seperated list of id's. How you let the editor select/create those id's is up to you and C1 won't interfere.